# Xcode: invalid variables view while debugging selected view

Tags: xcode, swift, debugging

I have a subclass of UIButton, I'm using it in a storyboard. I'm adding some sublayers to its layer in the layoutSubviews() function. It shows up live fine in the storyboard.

In the storyboard, I'm doing Editor->Debug Selected Views. The breakpoint I've set is hit, but I can't inspect variables like "self" or "layer"

[image]

Why is that?

(lldb) po self
error: :1:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'self'
self
^

(lldb) po layer
error: :1:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'layer'
layer
^

Xcode Version 6.3 (6D570)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Xcode 6.3 release notes:

Debugger

When using the debugger, the variables view may omit values for the current frame if the current function comes from a Swift framework.
Add -Xfrontend -serialize-debugging-options to the Other Swift Flags build setting for the framework. (20380047)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html

Comment: where the hell is Other Swift Options? Is that 'Other Swift Flags'?

Comment: thanks. goddamn apple, cannot even quote their stuff properly!

Answer (score 0):

I've had success using `fr v` instead of `po` in a lot of these cases. So for example instead of `po self.property` you can try `fr v self.property`

It also works really well when objects are referenced as protocols or superclasses (like `Error`) since it'll print out its ACTUAL type not the current dynamic type.